# Emulator Not Working in Eclipse

Tags: android

Hello everyone I can't seem to figure out why my emulator isn't working and I don't get the error in the console

Here is what it says in the console

```
[2011-08-24 16:28:59 - MePlayer] Android Launch!
[2011-08-24 16:28:59 - MePlayer] adb is running normally.
[2011-08-24 16:28:59 - MePlayer] Performing com.meplayer.afajje.MePlayer activity launch
[2011-08-24 16:28:59 - MePlayer] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Droid' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-08-24 16:28:59 - MePlayer] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Droid'
[2011-08-24 16:29:01 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files.
[2011-08-24 16:29:01 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-08-24 16:29:01 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Comment: Dumb question, but have you created an emulator in the AVD console? Just throwing it out there...

Comment: Please be more specific about "not working". Have you tried a second AVD?

Comment: @transistor1 yes I did, I made one it didn't work then created another one still the same error thing

Comment: @transistor, he created avd 'Droid'.

Comment: @WarrenFaith yes I have, but it still gives me the same error and won't start the emulator

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski ah ok, missed that. Thanks

Comment: This happend to me recently when I updated my android SDK

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski im not sure if I updated, but how do you go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs on Version 12/13. You SDK path contains spaces. Move it to space-*less* path or if it is in Program Files change the path in `Window->Preferences` select `Android`

`C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk`

Comment: The SDK doesn't contain spaces and i've check the preferences and its directed to the correct path

Comment: Hmm...I cant think of anything else. Read here

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18317

Comment: actually i take back what I said, I place the Android folder from Progam Files (x86) and put it on my desktop and my emulator run, thank you bud :)